# Align table and div inside td to top and bottom respectively

Tags: html, css

I have a site and i want to align the table and div element inside the td to top and bottom respectively. Right now i have design which is something like this

[image]

and i want to make it something like this

[image]

The code for right side is something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code? and first try to use `position absolute` on the  `aligned bottom`

Comment: it is working fine dude http://www.villasangiovese.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Personally w3 is easier to read the mozilla site. It has the editor which shows examples and is helpful to new developers.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site?

Comment: please recheck

http://goo.gl/2AWfGO

i have removed the margin top css, as it wasn't working good there

Comment: Just a side note tables are not the best way to layout a page. This would be much easier to solve if it wasn't a table.